# Predicting customers for a new product

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Hey I am struggling to understand how would I find out from a pool of existing customers, who would purchase a new product I am about to launch. I could think of a few methods but I am not sure if this is the correct direction.

1. Finding the closeness of the new product to already existing ones (they will have similar parameters) and consider the customers who are buying those closer products.
2. Make it a classification problem where the target is the customer (one hot encoded) and the features are the product information. When the new product is released, I can get probability of purchase by each customer.

Can someone please guide me to the possible solution?